# Difference between Bravais lattice, point lattice and space lattice

Tags: solid-state-physics, terminology, definition, crystals, lattice-model

I am good at crystallographic terminologies. Can somebody explain to me what is the difference between Bravais lattice, point lattice, and space lattice, if any?